# Editing detail entities via redux-form: multiple forms or re-use same form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Given that I am using redux-form, consider this rather basic CRUD example. I have a list of Customers on a page. There is an edit button on each entry in the list. Clicking on the edit button navigates to a new page (via react router) which has a form in it to edit and submit updates to the server.

Given the above example, should I have a single form and keep reinitializing values to the new customer each time it is navigated to (via  different customer ID prop) ? Or, should there be multiple redux-forms (ie: multiple redux-form states) for each potential customer id?

So my state could look like if it were to re-use the same form state. It would keep reseting to latest values each time the component which shows the form mounts. So they click to edit customer 2, load customer 2 into this form state. They later click to edit customer 3, overwrite customer 2 with customer 3's intitialValues:

```
 {
  ...
  customerForm: {...redux-form-stuff...} 
 }
```

... Or, I suppose it could create a new form state for each customer id. With no overwriting. But it would have to dynamically create new form states on the fly (not even sure how to do that, I'm new to reactjs). But it would allow it to keep the original values between page navigation.

```
 {
  ...
  customerForm2: {...redux-form-stuff...}
  customerForm3: {...redux-form-stuff...} 
  customerForm4: {...redux-form-stuff...} 
  customerForm5: {...redux-form-stuff...} 
  ...and so on...
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice here is to only have one form type as far as `redux-form` is concerned. So you would have your `CustomerForm` component that is connected to `redux-form` and then like you said each time it is loaded you pipe-in the initial values from the state tree.

Since you will only ever be showing one form at a time, there isn't really reason to keep around all the different form states in memory, especially if the initial values are just values derived from state.